# Generate colored android Bitmap from numeric data

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

Suppose I have an array of integer data, with values ranging from 0 to 100. I would like to generate a android.graphics.Bitmap with the color of each pixel representing the numeric value of the corresponding array element. E.g. suppose I want the following bitmap colors for the following value ranges: 0-25: red, 26-50: orange, 51-75: blue, 76-100: purple.  I see how to create a pixmap from the numeric data, but the colors of course don't correspond to what I want.

```
int[] data = new int[width*height];

[ ...Load data array (values 0-100) from file...]

// Can create a bitmap from data - but how to get wanted colors???
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics, data, width, height, someConfig);
```

Can someone please outline the steps I need to take, mapping the raw values to the appropriate colors?

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int drawColor=Color.TRANSPARENT; //fallback
if(data[index]<=25)
    drawColor=Color.RED;
else if(data[index]<=50)
    drawColor=0xFFFF9900;
else if(data[index]<=75)
    drawColor=Color.BLUE;
else if(data[index]<=100)
    drawColor=0xFF8000FF;
bitmap.setPixel(x, y, drawColor);
```

Comment: Great - nice and simple!

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the proportion of change in color and value, refer to

http://www.cs.uml.edu/~haim/ColorCenter/ColorCenterColormaps.htm